# GitBash icon not showing correctly in taskbar [WIN10]

Tags: icons, windows-10, git-bash

This is not a big problem but it's bothering me. I've installed it in Program Files (x86), already found many old solutions which didn't work for me. I can't install it in another location. I've tried to change the ico to a different one located in a path without spaces, but it didn't work.

Git CMD icon works fine (but I don't like this terminal), the problem persists only with GitBash icon

Can someone help?

Comment: Please don't add solved to title, the accept indicates that you got a solution that works for you, to learn more see [tour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon was missing in older versions (2.10: see [issue 870](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/870#issuecomment-244565464))

In your case, make sure to install the [latest 64-bits version](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (in `Program Files`, not `Program Files (x86)`)

That would be: [`Git-2.15.0-64-bit.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.15.0.windows.1/Git-2.15.0-64-bit.exe).

---

Update Oct. 2022: this is still working correctly.

[image: icon]

Comment: Just tested and this worked. Strange tho, I didn't get any update notification while using Git (I had v 2.12.something). Thanks!

Comment: for me this did not work with Git-2.38.1-64-bit taken from git-scm.com

Comment: @FabrizioMiano You would need to open a new issue for that. I have edited the answer to illustrate this seems to work as intended (W11, Git-2.38.1-64-bit ).

Comment: Thanks for that @VonC however, the question is for W10

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it could be purely because of the shortcut referring to a previous installation which no longer exists. Check properties by right-clicking on git bash terminal's taskbar icon.

If that's the case

- Delete the shortcut or
- Replace the path with the current installation directory.

Comment: Yep, this was the case for me. Thanks